# Return AICc from a GWR model

Tags: r, anova, gwr, spgwr

I have run a geographically weighted regression (GWR) in R with the spgwr package and would like to extract the value of AICc and save it as separately.

However, this does not seem to be possible. So, what other ways are there to extract or calculate the AICc of GWR?

Alternatively, if this is not possible, how can we compare an GWR model and OLS model? The anova() is not very helpful, because it does not report a p-value.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you print the returned gwr object, it will print aicc value(if you run the gwr()method for global test instead of fit.point prediction)

if you want the p value or compare gwr with OLS 
you can run the method
BFC02.gwr.test(x)
x is gwr object

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, what I needed was to be able to save the AICc as a separate variable and use it later on, without having to enter it manually in the code. A friend of mine pointed out that this is possible, if you type gwr.model$results$AICh.